# How to keep back-up of any item of "Sitecore content Editor" tree?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

How to keep back-up of any item in sitecore. If any item can be needed in future again and i want to revert all setting  and content of old items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your business requirements. You could:

1. Use item versions in Sitecore
2. Serialise items and store the serialisation output in SVN
3. Generate packages containing the item you want to backup and store the package in SVN

Comment: Which is easiest to use and give me a good link of step by step tutorial. I work in sitecore content editor.

Comment: Here is a video showing how to serialize items

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7CK2HxyChow

You would still need to take care of the svn side after the items are serialized.

Answer (score 3):

You should look into Hedgehog's Team Development for Sitecore. It allows you to manage Sitecore Items in SVN or TFS.

http://www.hhogdev.com/products/team-development-for-sitecore.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to store the items in SVN I would use serialization.  I believe that part of the reason Sitecore added that feature.

One thing to consider would be some sort of automated process to serialize the content you want in SVN.  For example if you say wanted to keep all template changes in SVN you could tie into the save event, then when a template is saved use the API to serialize the affected template and check it into SVN.

Comment: Depending on your situation you may also want to check this out.

http://www.hhogdev.com/products/team-development-for-sitecore.aspx

It is a product that tackles this exact problem.